# Returning NULL pointer vs. return calloc(1,1);

Tags: c, null, malloc, free

What is the difference between

```
char *f(int size,...)
{
....
if(size == 0)
  return (0);
}
```

and

```
char *f(int size,...)
{
.....
if (size == 0)
  return (calloc(1,1));
}
```

And, how it is related to using free() to output of f. What is the advantage or use cases of the second.

To make more sense, I am copying the exercise I am dealing with.

> - Write a function that will concatenate all the strings pointed by strs separated by sep.
> - size is the number of strings in strs
> - if size is 0, you must return an empty string that you can free().
> - Here’s how it should be prototyped :

```
char *ft_strjoin(int size, char **strs, char *sep);
```

Edit note: After reading comments, I realize that question wants realloc(1,1) instead of the buggy code I copy-pasted earlier `(char *)malloc(sizeof(char))`

Comment: The first returns a null pointer, and the second returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated , uninitialized byte (which you will later have to free to avoid a leak).  It's hard to understand why you'd want the latter.

Comment: I have no idea why someone would allocate a 1-byte piece of memory on an error. It is perfectly safe to call `free` on a null pointer. But both of the code examples are poor, in some way. The first should return `NULL` rather than `(0)`. The second should not cast the return value as `char *` because a `void *` is already automatically promoted to whatever pointer it needs to be. Unnecessary casts can hide problems. And `sizeof(char)` is simply `1`, by definition.

Comment: To make it simple: the second variant is totally pointless. What **exactly** are you trying to achieve? How would `f` be called and used? [Edit] and show a use case.

Comment: @user I don't understand how the exercise is related to your question.

Comment: To return "an empty string that you can free", you need to explicitly set it to the null character.  Otherwise it's an uninitialized string, not an empty string.  You can use `strdup("")` to create a new, free-able empty string.  Or you can call `malloc`, strore the null character, and return it.

Comment: @Jabberwocky For the solution of the exercise it is written if (size == 0) return ((char *)malloc(sizeof(char)))); What if, I would return 0 for that case. What would i have missed?

Comment: @user returning `(char *)malloc(sizeof(char))` doesn't work.  It returns a pointer to an uninitialized, one-element-long character array, not an empty string.  In particular, there's no way for the caller to even know it's meant to be an empty string, since it could contain anything.  Basically, it's a bug.  If they're trying to tell you that's the solution, then they don't know what they're doing, and you can simply point out to them that there's no guarantee the returned pointer will point to an empty string.

Comment: @user17732522 It is a repository of some student. Gererally, the students of the ecole 42 pushes their code only if they got full grade.
 He writes ft_strjoin.c
to answer to exercise. However,  the file ft_strjoin_main.c is for testing the answer but not submitted as a part of solution.

Comment: `return ((char *)malloc(sizeof(char)))` should probably be `char *result = malloc(1);  result[0] = 0; return result;`. Or simpler `return calloc(1, 1);`, `calloc` being similar to `malloc` but initializes the allocated memory to 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right. I understand that the question wants if (size ==0) return calloc(1, 1);  But, what is the benefit?

Comment: @user the benefit is that it eliminates a bug. With the original solution it returns a pointer to an uninitialized byte and not a pointer to an empty string. With `calloc` it returns a pointer to a null byte, which is by definition an empty string.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks but why we need strdup. What is the difference between return(""); and return(strdup(""));

Comment: @user You can't free `""`, and the instructions specifically said it needed to be freeable.  They went out of their way to make a point of that.  `""` is a constant string, not from the dynamic memory heap.